# Ubuntu reports significantly less ram that I actually have

Tags: 20.04, ram

Recently specifically after ubuntu updates, and after messing around with installing/uninstalling virtual box on ubuntu, my machine(XPS 13 9360) starter reporting only 1.4gb(which was not the case before) of ram.
`free -m` output:

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available 
Mem:           1421         753          87         177         580         237 
Swap:          2047         983        1064
```

`neofetch` output:

```
OS: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS x86_64 
Host: XPS 13 9360 
Kernel: 5.4.0-86-generic 
Uptime: 14 mins 
Packages: 2863 (dpkg), 10 (brew), 23 (snap) 
Shell: zsh 5.8 
Resolution: 1920x1080 
DE: Plasma 
WM: KWin 
WM Theme: Layan 
Theme: Layan [Plasma], Breeze [GTK2/3] 
Icons: Tela [Plasma], Tela [GTK2/3] 
Terminal: konsole 
CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz 
GPU: Intel UHD Graphics 620 
Memory: 922MiB / 1421MiB
```

BIOS reports 16gb, dual booting into windows reports also 16gb.
Is there anything I could do to fix this? Or should I reinstall? Help would be appreciated as stuff is crashing due to lack of ram linux is seeing.

**EDIT**:
`sudo dmidecode -t memory` output:

```
# dmidecode 3.2
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 3.0.0 present.

Handle 0x0038, DMI type 16, 23 bytes
Physical Memory Array
        Location: System Board Or Motherboard
        Use: System Memory
        Error Correction Type: None
        Maximum Capacity: 16 GB
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Number Of Devices: 2

Handle 0x0039, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0038
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: Row Of Chips
        Set: None
        Locator: System Board Memory
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: LPDDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Manufacturer: SK Hynix
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: H9CCNNNCLGALAR-NVD
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.25 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.25 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V

Handle 0x003A, DMI type 17, 40 bytes
Memory Device
        Array Handle: 0x0038
        Error Information Handle: Not Provided
        Total Width: 64 bits
        Data Width: 64 bits
        Size: 8192 MB
        Form Factor: Row Of Chips
        Set: None
        Locator: System Board Memory
        Bank Locator: Not Specified
        Type: LPDDR3
        Type Detail: Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered)
        Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Manufacturer: SK Hynix
        Serial Number: Not Specified
        Asset Tag: Not Specified
        Part Number: H9CCNNNCLGALAR-NVD
        Rank: 2
        Configured Memory Speed: 2133 MT/s
        Minimum Voltage: 1.25 V
        Maximum Voltage: 1.25 V
        Configured Voltage: 1.2 V
```

**EDIT 2**:
Did a little more digging and found that command `dmesg | grep Memory` returns failure to map memory:

```
[    0.109763] Memory: 1364404K/16498176K available (14339K kernel code, 2400K rwdata, 5016K rodata, 2736K init, 4964K bss, 15133772K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.151677] efi: memattr: Failed to map EFI Memory Attributes table @ 0x6e0a5018
[    0.167205] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
```

Which can be linked to:
[this](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1944019)

Comment: does `grep MemTotal /proc/meminfo`  also report only 1,4GB?

Comment: What is the output of `sudo dmidecode -t memory`?

Comment: @Bruni here's the output for the command `MemTotal:        1455608 kB`.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I've updated the description with the command output you gave me

Comment: What happens with `free` if you boot in recovery mode or single user mode?
This can help you find the culprit.

Comment: I've run `free -m` in both recovery and single user modes, and they both return the same thing with total memory being `1421` which is what I get running it in terminal, do you have any suggestion as to what this might mean? I'm a little lost now @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some looking into I found that I had older bios ver (2.15), after updating bios to latest 2.16, things are back to normal. I'm assuming this started happening due to latest ubuntu updates rolled out.